# NSTableView guarantee data display

Tags: cocoa, process, nstableview

The main GUI of my app has a NSTableView, controlled by its own controller class. This class loads data into the table once by launching and parsing the output of a process. This is done in the

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
```

method of the controller class. The table shows up right on startup, so it means that before the GUI is displayed, the parsing of the process output should be done.

Now the problem is that when the GUI is shown (my app startup is slow, which means that process has been launched), the table is sometimes empty or is sometimes loaded with data. This is random. **So how do I get the table to be always loaded with data on startup?**

`reloadData` does not work! and I also use `[NSTask waitUntilExit];`

Comment: Could you explain how you are providing data to your table, through bindings or delegation?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I often make an app "load completely" before the window shows:

Uncheck the "visible at startup" for your window in Interface Builder. Then create an `IBOutlet NSWindow *window;` in your AppDelegate. And finally, in your AppDelegate, implement the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method and add `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];` into this method.

This should work, because `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` will always be called after `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: no!! all of a sudden I retest my app and it is not working - still an empty table randomly (i am displaying window now using this method, confirmed)

Comment: Are you sure that makeKeyAndOrderFront is the last thing you do in applicationDidFinishLaunching? Also, if you now get rid of makeKeyAndOrderFront, does the window stop showing? (Just want to make sure, in case you sneaked in some window showing elsewhere.)

Comment: the window doesnt appear without `makeKeyAndOrderFront`, and this is the only thing in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have no idea what's going on. The only thing I can imagine is that you put some delayed work in a different thread using, say, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: or dispatch_async. That could cause something like this to happen. Other than that, I'm all out of ideas :(